# how to use excel solver to get the shares weights minimize a risk indicator given a fixed profitability I want to make?

Tags: excel, solver

I post this question after being redirected from Quantitative Finance's forum.

I want to minimize a risk indicator given a fixed profitability I want to make from five financial shares. Therefore I applied the solver from Excel to get the weight in percentage I should use from my constraints and objective function.

Yet after trying to set the expected return to actual values expected return, (like Auke Plantiga does in his video on youtube)  I always get an error that the solver canno't find a realisable solution.

**Therefore how to use excel solver to get the shares weights minimize a risk indicator given a fixed profitability I want to make?**

Here is how I set the solver
[image]

Here is the error message I get
[image]

Comment: What is the formula of the expected return and of the risk?

Comment: Portfolio model of the form `min x'Qx, sum(x) = 1, r'x >= R, x>=0` should be easy to solve. Including Excel's GRG solver. Of course R can be chosen too large that no feasible portfolio exists,